# Mac Automator - Compress (ZIP) a folder and rename as original folder name without the entirety of the path

Tags: macos, automator, pathname

*Hi all, total newbie to any kind of programming, but I've written an Automator workflow to do  a repetitive task I do daily. Basically I'm prepping artwork files and folders to send out to printers.
The steps are as follows:*

Set Value of Variable (variable is ArtworkFolder)

> where I drop the artwork folder containing the illustrator file and
>   PDF

Get Specified Finder Items

> locates a file on a RAID server

Copy Finder Items (to ArtworkFolder)

> copies said file into the folder

Ask for Confirmation -

> prompts user to select an updated PDF

Ask for Finder Items -

> opens the folder where the new PDF sits

Copy Finder Items (to ArtworkFolder)-

> copies PDF file into the folder (overwriting older files)

Ask for Confirmation

> prompts user to select print guidelines

Ask for Finder Items

> opens the folder where the print guidelines sit

Copy Finder Items (to variable ArtworkFolder) -

> copies print guidelines into the folder
>
> THIS IS WHERE I THINK IT MAY BE GOING AWRY

Get Value of Variable (ArtworkFolder)

> this is supposed to get the name of the original folder

Get Specified Finder Items

> and all its contents

Create Archive

> Then Zip the whole lot together
>
> But it zips it with the name Archive.zip which I don't want so...

Rename Finder Items: Replace Text

> which is set to find "Archive" in basename only ignoring Case. then
>   replace that with the variable ArtworkFolder
>
> but it renames the folder with the entire path
>
> I've tried to strip out the path by adding…

Rename Finder Items: Replace Text

> which is set to find everything in the path basename only up to the
>   unique folder name and replace with nothing (eg I left the Replace box
>   blank)
>
> But then it duplicates the folder name like this:

00000- Test Artwork Folder/00000- Test Artwork Folder.zip

> All I want is to original folder name (00000- Test Artwork Folder) as
>   the zip file name.
>
> Any tips would be greatly received!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, Automator doesn't have an included action to get file names, so you will need to use a third-party action or do it yourself.  A **Run AppleScript** action can be used, but either way, note that you will need to save the workflow items and use the **Ignore Input** option as appropriate around getting the names, so you don't get them mixed in with the file items (also note that the workflow and action items are a *list*).

To get the name of a single item, something like the following can be inserted into your workflow, where the variable for the name can be used in the rename action:

**Set Value of Variable** { Variable: *Original Input* } -- stash current items

**Run AppleScript**: -- get the name

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set {theContainer, theName, theExtension} to getNamePieces from (first item of input)
    return theName
end run

to getNamePieces from somePath
    tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (somePath as text)
        set _container to path of container
        set {_name, _extension} to {name, name extension}
    end tell
    if _extension is not "" then
        set _name to text 1 thru -((count _extension) + 2) of _name -- just the name part
        set _extension to "." & _extension
    end if
    return {_container, _name, _extension}
end getNamePieces
```

**Set Value of Variable** { Variable: *Item Name* }

**Get Value of Variable** { Variable: *Original Input* }  (Ignore Input) -- continue workflow